# Can I reverse my Logitech keyboard's touchpad scroll direction?

Tags: windows-8, logitech-keyboard

Is it possible to reverse the vertical scroll of the touchpad on my Logitech Wireless Touch Keyboard (K400r) in the Logitech Setpoint program?

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: **No**, not in SetPoint.

In [a relevant post in the Logitech forums from 2013 August 8](https://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Windows-8-Pro-Logitech-K400r-Scrolling-Direction/m-p/1071881), a Logitech support technician states

```
This is not an option in Logitech Setpoint for Windows either.
```

This was my experience, today. Based on another forum post from a different Logitech support tech, I installed SetPoint in an attempt to accomplish the same goal (reverse scroll direction on a Logitech `K400` wireless keyboard/touchpad combo) and fiddled with it for a couple of hours.

---

Long answer: **Yes**, *if you are willing to do some registry surfing*.

The technician goes on to cite a registry edit "for the sake of information". Specifically:

```
Registry Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Enum > HID > VID_046D&PID_C52B > Device Parameters (All)

For Vertical Scrolling: All Device Parameters
Entry Name: FlipFlopWheel
Control Value: 0
Reversed Value: 1

For Horizontal Scrolling: All Device Parameters
Entry Name: FlipFlopHScroll
Control Value: 0
Reversed Value: 1
```

Then, the tech discourages the reader from manipulating the registry. Reasonable advice, considering that the suggested edit is not straight-forward.

I am using the `Logitech Unifying Software` on `Windows 10` and have additional pointing devices attached through the unifier and otherwise. At `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID`, I found 18 member keys with names that started with `VID_046D&PID_C52B` but continued with additional specifiers. I.e. by studying the values in the subkeys, I eventually determined that my Logitech wireless trackball (a *separate* device) was represented as:

```
VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1203&MI_02&Qid_1028&WI_02&Class_00000004
```

and the **trackpad** component of my `K400` was represented as:

```
VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1203&MI_02&Qid_4024&WI_01&Class_0000001E&Col02
```

Each of these keys has a complex-looking subkey that itself has two subkeys: `Properties` (protected against access) and `Device Parameters`, **the one we are looking for**. On my system, the *particular* `FlipFlopHScroll` and `FlipFlopWheel` that I wanted were found in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1203&MI_02&Qid_4024&WI_01&Class_0000001E&Col02\8&262edd47&0&0001\Device Parameters
```

If you can identify the correct path for your setup, right click on the two `FlipFlop` data elements (to `Modify...` in `regedit`) and change them from `0` to `1`. I noticed the desired effect after I restarted my machine.

---

To aide your search, try searching the `HID` key for the string `logitech`. The 'complex-sounding' subkey for the appropriate subkey of `HID` will have some helpful info. Specifically, my

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1203&MI_02&Qid_4024&WI_01&Class_0000001E&Col02\8&262edd47&0&0001
```

has the data element named `DeviceDesc` with the value

```
@oem23.inf,%hidcordlessunifyingmouse%;Logitech HID-compliant Unifying Mouse
```

On my system, this was one of two such keys. (I have two mouse pointers managed by the `Logitech Unifying Software`.)

Comment: You can find the exact name by looking at the device properties, like in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/GVeYvp8.png (which can be found through https://i.imgur.com/3KREUkQ.png ).
In addition, you don't have to restart Windows. You can just unplug the device and plug it back.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scroll direction is still "wrong" in 2018, and there is still no UI setting for changing it. Luckily, this solution still works.

Comment: My registry key was VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_01&Col01 instead of the one mentioned above, and the names of the variables I toggled to 1 were "FlipFlopHScroll" and "FlipFlopWheel", but with these minor changes, the method still worked for me!  (after taking out the usb dongle, turning off then on the keyboard, and then reinserting the dongle).

Comment: In late 2020, Logitech Options allows this configuration, at least for the Logitech K400:

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893

Comment: this method does not work for windows 11. I found the key 
HID\VID_046D&PID_C52B&MI_01&Col01, turned the values of flipflop variables to 1, restarted laptop, removed dongle, swithced of keyboard and reinserted dongle but didnt help, model is logitech k400+, default direction was fingers swipe down. scroller moves down, bottom content emerges towards top), rather setting Content tracks fingers in Logitech Options software worked

Answer (score 5):

Wow....Logitech Options software is a 201MB download. Which is a behemoth just to change a registry key. :\

Well I went ahead and tried it, on Win7, for my K400. The software seemed to be only looking for a K400+, so it never could find my K400. It also introduced a phantom "stuck arrow key". So I had to pull the dongle out and de-install "Logitech Options". Then that problem went away.

So I had success with the direct registry edit, described above. However, I recommend an easier way to find the correct key:

1. Physically pull out all Logitech input devices, except the keyboard.
2. In Device Manager, double-click MICE > Logitech HID-Compliant Unifying/Cordless mouse.
3. Click on the DETAILS tab
4. For PROPERTY drop-down, select HARDWARE IDs
5. Right-click and copy the first value in the list. It should look something like... HID\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1210&MI_02&Qid_4024&WI_01&Class_0000001E&Col02
6. Open up REGEDIT.EXE, and right-click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum and choose FIND...
7. Paste into the FIND criteria box, and click OK. Open up the DEVICE PARAMETERS sub-key and that's where you add/edit the DWORD values, as per above post.
8. Pull out and in again, your logitech dongle, then turn off and on the keyboard, and voila!
9. Reinsert any other dongles you removed in step 1

{Mod: I couldn't find a way to ask for my edited answer to be re-instated, nor was told it would automatically be reconsidered after the edit, so I've gone ahead and re-posted this as a new answer. Please let me know if I'm missing something, as I'm new hear and keen to learn how things work. :) }

Answer (score 3):

In late 2020, Logitech Options allows this configuration (at least for the Logitech K400, which DOES answer the OPs question)

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893

[image: Logitech Options]

Comment: There is an older K400 keyboard which OP and others refer to (it also looks different). It is not supported by the new Logitech Options.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for reverse scrolling on Logitech T650 touchpad, the setting is managed via SetPoint Settings utility (Mouse properties -> tab 'SetPoint Settings') -> tab 'Scroll' -> Scroll Options button (bottom right) -> Scroll Direction (checkbox)